# How to shutdown jshell at the end of the script?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

How to instruct `jshell` to terminate at the end of the script similarly to interpreters of other languages like for example `python3` or `node`?

Following command

```
./jshell -q /tmp/shell.java
```

with script `/tmp/shell.java`

```java
System.out.println("Hello world");
```

prints

```
Hello world
jshell>
```

and waits for further commands. I'd like it to stop immediately at the end of the file.

I'm looking for something more elegant than `System.exit(0);` at the end of the script.

Comment: I've been using a .jsh file extension to indicate a file to be run with jshell, since .java implies it can be compiled by javac.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Inside the script, use the jshell command `/exit`.
This will exit jshell at the end of your script.

Check this reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-465BA4F5-E77D-456F-BCB7-D826AC1E18AE

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to have an exit file:

**`exit.jsh`**

```
/exit
```

And then run:

```
./jshell --startup myscript.jsh --startup exit.jsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```bash
cat /tmp/shell.java | jshell -
```

Should work the same in bash and windows powershell